Auth_remoteuser MediaWiki extension gives internal Parser::parse error
I've just installed a MediaWiki 1.41. After adding the Auth_remoteuser extension (for release 1.41, though I've tried also with 1.40 and 1.39 versions) I get this error. Removing the extension, all works well again. Why is that happening?
The stack trace is as follows:
/wiki/Pagina_principal MWException: Parser state cleared while parsing.
Did you call Parser::parse recursively? Lock is held by:
#0 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(882): Parser->lock()
#1 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(4821): Parser->preprocess()
#2 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/MessageCache.php(1442): Parser->transformMsg()
#3 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1464): MessageCache->transform()
#4 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1011): Message->transformText()
#5 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1059): Message->format()
#6 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/linker/Linker.php(2207): Message->text()
#7 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/linker/Linker.php(2388): MediaWiki\Linker\Linker::titleAttrib()
#8 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(236): MediaWiki\Linker\Linker::tooltipAndAccesskeyAttribs()
#9 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(183): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->applyLinkTitleAttribs()
#10 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(254): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->makeLink()
#11 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentListItem.php(138): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->getTemplateData()
#12 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentListItem.php(221): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentListItem->makeListItem()
#13 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentMenu.php(166): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentListItem->getTemplateData()
#14 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/Skin.php(2470): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentMenu->getTemplateData()
#15 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(641): Skin->getPortletData()
#16 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(181): SkinTemplate->getPortletsTemplateData()
#17 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinMustache.php(125): SkinTemplate->getTemplateData()
#18 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/skins/Vector/includes/SkinVectorLegacy.php(161): SkinMustache->getTemplateData()
#19 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinMustache.php(92): MediaWiki\Skins\Vector\SkinVectorLegacy->getTemplateData()
#20 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(174): SkinMustache->generateHTML()
#21 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/Output/OutputPage.php(2947): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#22 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(978): MediaWiki\Output\OutputPage->output()
#23 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(613): MediaWiki->main()
#24 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#25 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#26 {main}

Backtrace:

from /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(6309)
#0 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(882): Parser->lock()
#1 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/parser/Parser.php(4821): Parser->preprocess()
#2 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/MessageCache.php(1442): Parser->transformMsg()
#3 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1464): MessageCache->transform()
#4 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1011): Message->transformText()
#5 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/language/Message.php(1059): Message->format()
#6 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/linker/Linker.php(2207): Message->text()
#7 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/linker/Linker.php(2388): MediaWiki\Linker\Linker::titleAttrib()
#8 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(236): MediaWiki\Linker\Linker::tooltipAndAccesskeyAttribs()
#9 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(183): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->applyLinkTitleAttribs()
#10 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentLink.php(254): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->makeLink()
#11 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentListItem.php(138): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentLink->getTemplateData()
#12 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentListItem.php(221): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentListItem->makeListItem()
#13 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/components/SkinComponentMenu.php(166): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentListItem->getTemplateData()
#14 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/Skin.php(2470): MediaWiki\Skin\SkinComponentMenu->getTemplateData()
#15 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(641): Skin->getPortletData()
#16 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(181): SkinTemplate->getPortletsTemplateData()
#17 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinMustache.php(125): SkinTemplate->getTemplateData()
#18 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/skins/Vector/includes/SkinVectorLegacy.php(161): SkinMustache->getTemplateData()
#19 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinMustache.php(92): MediaWiki\Skins\Vector\SkinVectorLegacy->getTemplateData()
#20 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(174): SkinMustache->generateHTML()
#21 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/Output/OutputPage.php(2947): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#22 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(978): MediaWiki\Output\OutputPage->output()
#23 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(613): MediaWiki->main()
#24 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#25 /aplicaciones/dp08/dp08_bcnwiki/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#26 {main}

Edit: changing $wgLanguajeCode from  'es' to 'en', the problem disappears. Should that be a bug in Auth_remoteuser Spanish translation? Or anywhere else?
Edit: changing to Italian or Russian works ok, but French also fails. I will have to assume there is some sort of problem with the translation of this extension.
